# How to solve it-updating plugins in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

> I have made modifications in several of the plugins in wordpress. But
>   these plugins are now outdated. I have to submit the project to the
>   client. The client is asking me to update the plugins. But the problem
>   is that when I would update plugins, the changes that I made in
>   plugins would have gone away. So, I want to ask is there any concept
>   of child plugin in wordpress and if so, how to create it; so that my
>   changes would remain intact.

Comment: You can hide the updates so there will be no updates shown :)

Comment: how to hide the updates?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which plugins are you using so I am giving an example of [WooCommerce Delivery Date](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-delivery-date/) plugin. I have disabled updates for that plugin and I have used below code to achieve it :

```
/* Function which remove Plugin Update Notices – WooCommerce Delivery Date*/
function disable_plugin_updates( $value ) {
   unset( $value->response['woocommerce-delivery-date/woocommerce-delivery-date.php'] );
   return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'disable_plugin_updates' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the version of the plugin to more than the latest version :

```
Go to wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/your-plugin.php
```

generally your-plugin.php is the main file of the plugin and it is having version in the top commented line.

Edit the version of the each plugin

Otherwise install a plugin your admin that will disable updates. Get this plugin from here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to keep a good name, I'd find a way to achieve making the necessary changes without modifying plugins in the first place (this is a bad practice, as I'm sure you know). When people purchase your product or services, they want to know they're not getting a "bad egg" or a "lemon deal"; and that their investment is *actually an investment* and not a complete waste of effort, money and overall time.

Updates are important! What if they are handling sensitive information on their site? What if their host requires a specific plugin to be a certain version?

Make your change in another way, [write your own plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), include the functionality [in a child-theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained); you can even handle certain "modifications" by using jQuery to manipulate elements in the DOM (include it in your child theme).

Just don't do something regrettable as some others have suggested. This is only going to last until the next update is released and lead to trouble, a bad reputation, or legal action. Integrity is all a man has. If you throw it away, you're worthless.